# Rails application with CAS authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cas, rubycas

I've been considering CAS as a backend for authentication, and found RubyCAS.

Unfortunatelly, to test RubyCAS I have to install the server, setup an SSL infrastructure, start the server to, finally, test my application.

Is there a way of testing rubycas-client without setting up the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't work with RubyCAS without server.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to have both applications ready. they should talk each other